# Customized Password Reset URL for Django Rest API Password Reset

Tags: django, passwords, restful-authentication

I am new to Django and have implemented a password reset endpoint for my rest API using the `django-rest-passwordreset` library. It works fantastic, but I want to customize the url returned in my email to include "https://" and domain name before the path and token so that the full URL is shown in the email.

As of now, the email send me a path like this:

`/password-reset/?token=random_string_of_characters_are_here`

I'd like it to email me something like this:

`https://mywebsite.com/password-reset/?token=random_string_of_characters_are_here`

Answer (score 0):

what i do is add the url in context :

```py
from django.conf import settings

context.update({"FRONT_URL": settings.FRONT_URL})
content = render_to_string("emails/reset.html".format(template), context)
```

I populate `FRONT_URL` in `settings.py` and i can use `{{ FRONT_URL }}` in my template.

I use `context.update` so i can just add `FRONT_URL` to other `context` values